# Vagrant Synced Directory Influencing GCC Compile

Tags: c++, c, linux, gcc, vagrant

I have a large C/C++ project that was recently ported from Solaris to Linux. I am in the process of setting up a common linux development environment using a vagrant/virtualbox virtual machine. I thought it would be a good idea to allow developers to keep source code on their host machine within a vagrant synced folder and then to build it within the guest OS. However, whenever I build the source in the guest VM, somehow GCC fails with the following:

```
In file included from foobar.cpp:72:
../foobar.h:270: error: ‘uint32_t’ does not name a type
../foobar.h:273: error: ‘uint32_t’ does not name a type
../foobar.h:304: error: ‘WordCountType’ does not name a type
```

So, it seems that we are missing an include to stdint.h right? Well, I can actually add an include for this and compilation continues (until other problems are hit).

The mysterious part is that if I move the source code from the synced folder on the guest machine to one that is not within the vboxsf mount and run the build again. Everything works and the compilation completes successful.

What's going on here?

Comment: "if I move the source code from the synced folder on the guest machine to one that is not within the vboxsf mount" : same OS ? same versions ?

Comment: What does GCC's `-v` option say in each case? Do the search directories look right?

Comment: The problem might be in your build system. It probably assumes some directory structure that should be accessible with relative paths from the source code directory. I guess you can reproduce the problem by compiling the sources in any arbitrary root level directory (e.g. `/foo`).

Comment: In each case 'gcc -v' produces the exact same output (checked using diff to ensure). I also verified that the directory structure is not the issue by recreating the synced folder path without using vagrant vboxsf mount. It definitely seems to be related to the fact its a vagrant mount. Weird!